# Why does the `FAQ for Stack Exchange Sites` appear in the unanswered tab?

Tags: discussion, bug, unanswered-questions, meta-faq

When I opened the 'Unanswered' tab on the side, as shown below, the first question that shows up is the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).
[image]

Why is it there? Why isn't it removed from the 'Unanswered' tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a quirk of the system. The overall FAQ was written entirely as a question with links to other questions that form topic based FAQ and their answers. The system isn't smart enough to realise that this particular question should not have answers. It's an anomaly and probably one not really worth fixing.

The FAQ actually has quite a few answers but they've all been deleted because they are people asking questions about something they don't understand, something they should have asked separate questions about.

Comment: Why can't it be fixed? Can't it be like a special question? Or can't it be on the /faq page?

Comment: Why should it be fixed. It is a special question.

Comment: It is a bit misleading for new users: They open the Unanswered tab and instantly they see the FAQ.

Comment: @TheWebDeveloperBlog "It is a bit misleading for new users" Meta sites aren't really aimed at new users, they are for existing community members to discuss things, most newer users don't even know this site exists. If a new user is hunting for unanswered questions here to answer, they will probably have a bad time due to a lack on knowledge about Stack Exchange in general.

Comment: What I mean @MarkKirby is that let's say you've been a user on SO for 2 years, and then you come here and connect your SE account. After that, you go to unanswered, and then this FAQ appears first thing, so they open it, and then they're dazzled by the amount of content in it. Seriously?